# For a Single-Page-Website with a form at the end: Do I have to convert the index.html into index.php?

Tags: php, html

I am working on my first Website! Its a Single Page Design with a simple contact form (two input fields, a textarea and a checkbox and submit button) at the end of the page! The page is ready... the only thing that´s missing is the PHP for the contact form. When the contact form is submitted I would like to show a message (message delivered) on the same page!
My Question: For this purpose do I need to convert the whole index.html to index.php ??
It seems to be the only way for the action attribute of the form to stay on the same page! Or is it better to add also Ajax for this purpose? All tutorials use the index.php...

Please help!

Comment: The easiest solution would be to yes, change the extension to .php. You could also change your server's configuration to parse .html files as PHP pages.

Comment: I'm gonna say yes, but it depends on the configuration of your server.

Comment: You can't run PHP code on a `.html` page (easily), so you will need to change the file extension.

Comment: "Or is it better to add also Ajax for this purpose?"  It is a better experience for the user, yes.  I will require a little more knowledge on your part though.

Comment: You can use index.html for your homepage, but you will need to create a processing-form.php file to handle the submission of the form.  You'll need to add some javascript like you mentioned and submit the form with javascript.  

I've typically set it up so that after the user submits the form, a thank you message is displayed in its place.

Comment: or is it possible to write the contact-form in a separate file and include it in the index.html ?

Comment: @FlorianStöger if you want to include it, then change your index file to index.php.  I don't think you will get the benefit you want by doing that though.  You will need to hook it up to a script to process it and then use javascript to show a message.  In php, when you include code, it is as if it were all one file.  It just helps keep your code organized and prevents duplicating the same code over and over.  Best example of good use of an include is your header and footer would each be an include. if you have many pages, then you can just edit the single header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say yes, make it a .php file. A PHP file can have plain HTML in it. Your index.php could look something like this:

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['submitted'] ) ) {
    $message = 'Your email has been sent!';
    // Process your form and send email here
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if ( $message ) {
                echo "<div class='message'>$message</div>";
            }
        ?>
        <!--The rest of your body...-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

when you write one line in PHP language in your page you must convert to page.html to page.php

to show a message try to use this

```
echo "<script> alert('message delivered '); window.location.href='index.php';</script>" ;
```